# Should i use WordPress with BuddyPress or a custom Script?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I want to develop a website where people can find useful informations about other websites.

Something like DIGG.com

the problem is that i don't know to write code for WP or BP and i need a custom design and functionality

3 months ago i did not know about StackOverflow, and i think that a website that tell you about all the useful websites, will be useful, especially for the people that work in the IT domain

google gives you search results based on keywords, but most of the people need extras

www.linkbook.co is the domain, and i hope you get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddypress is great for community based websites, however if you want something like Digg, you should check out Pligg:

```
http://pligg.com/
```

It also has an active community with plenty of add-ons.

Worth checking out.

Comment: the thing is that i have a 2 gb/database restriction; and i have to split the information; i dont want to delte it; so i developed a new kind of system; and because i want to develop a short link system ... i need some databases ... lots of them ... the pligg is great, but ... what about my limitations ?

Comment: I used an older version of Pligg a while back and it was heavily spammed (millions of links!) before I added filters and started moderating the site. It got to about 1GB at it's worst, but after bulk removing spammers links and tidying up the database I had most of my space back. The newer version would have much better spam control.

Comment: i am currently developing the php script for linkbook.co, on linkbook.ro; i had a brainstorming session with my IT friends , and we decided to use my version, because its scalable, and we can always create new database, and create new local crawlers; wp, drupal and all the cms are heavy when running; i need something fast ... superfast ... i dont need to a 50 mb app